# Why is the record not showing up in the DB

Tags: php, database, shopping-cart

i am trying to create a custom solution for a client using their prior system. The client is using Miva which is a user friendly CMS type system to manage their store. The problem is prior to yesterday everytime i entered a record in the miva site it would show up in PHPmyadmin and I could query it and use the Custom solution. FOr some reason now when I create products in the admin I get no records in the DB.

The product is clearly there

but not stored in the db, any ideas on how and where is stored

Comment: Not appearing in your db/solution or not appearing phpmyadmin?

Comment: not appearing at all in PHPmyadmin, nothing is there but the product is clearly visible on the site

Comment: Didn't MIVA just release a big upgrade recently?  Did you/your host upgrade?  If so, that could be a cause, the product may be stored in another table/format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic dictates that either:

- Your query was wrong
- You're querying the wrong database
- The website does not relate to the database you're querying
- You're asleep and none of this is real.

Are you able to do a wildcard search for something specific like a piece of text or file location? If no errors are being thrown when you're adding items then it should be there.